# How to get a plot like this in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am very new to QGIS. I need any kind of tutorial where I can plot the overlapping areas inside the maps with different colors as attached in as an example image.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I'm getting hints from the post that an entire GIS course is needed for the task.

Answer (score 5):

A tutorial to find how to draw/edit polygons shouldnt be hard to find. Then you can use effects - drop shadow:

[image]

Comment: Nice trick! +1. What about the intersected areas?